# MongoDB aggregation framework availability

Tags: mongodb

The new aggregation framework will come with the 2.2 version.

They made some presentations and demos on that : 
http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/mongodbs-new-aggregation-framework

I does not found any development release on their site.

Does someone knows where I can test the new framework ?

Thanks

Comment: The [MongoDB 2.2 production release](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/) was end of August, 2012 .. so the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) is now widely available, and being used in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and install the development version 2.1, it is inside (and currently under development).

http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

But (at this stage) it is still a bit "young" (see for example a recent thread http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/3de5df85ce5b3713).

> MongoDB uses the standard “odd numbers are development, even are stable” versioning scheme. So the 2.1.x series is still under development, and you should probably wait until the release of 2.2.x to use this feature in production unless you fully understand what you’re doing.

I am looking for it as well. :-)